# Configure launch command in Code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks

I recently discovered [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/), and after downloading it, I decided to see if I could get it to work with Code::Blocks, so that I could easily test my applications to see how they performed when running as JavaScript.

I created a new compiler configuration, and set up all of the toolchain executables, except for the resource compiler (which doesn't seem to give me any problems), and the debugger. I wasn't really sure what to put in the debugger, because I remembered the debugger field as being a text-box. But when I looked, all that was there was a drop-down menu.

I managed to find a "Debugger" menu in the "Settings" menu, and when I opened it, there was a button called "Create config".

[image: Code::Blocks Debugger menu]

I created a new configuration, and pointed the executable path to "node.exe" (which runs .js files). I then went back to the compiler settings, and chose my new debugger in the drop-down.

I then tried to build and run a simple hello world application. But once it finished building, it gave me the message `Execution of '[my file] ' in '[my project folder] 'failed.` The actual build seemed to be successful, so I decided to manually run node.exe from the command line to see if I had configured the debugger incorrectly. And as I expected, it ran successfully.

While I was glad that I had successfully configured the compiler, I still was confused as to why the app didn't want to run. I also set Emscripten to create HTML files instead, to see if Code::Blocks would somehow recognize the appropriate program, and open it in the web browser instead. Of course that didn't work either.

What I am trying to figure out, is how I configure Code::Blocks' run command. Perhaps the debugger isn't even the right place to be looking. But I really need someone to help me figure out how I can configure this in Code::Blocks, as this is currently the only thing that is really giving me any trouble.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a little late, but I was able to get the codeblocks run button to run any command by using a few post-build steps. The reason I need this is because my laptop has nvidia "optimus" and in order for my output program to see the discreet graphics card, I have to run it with the optirun prefix. So I added the following to the post-build steps in build options:

```
mv $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE) $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE)_bin
echo #!/bin/sh > $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE)
echo optirun $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE)_bin >> $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE)
chmod +x $(TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE)
```

It basically renames the output binary and creates a script replacing the original output binary name. When pressing the run button, the script is executed instead of the output.

On windows, you might have an issue running an exe extensioned file as a batch script so what if you generate the output file with a bat extension like in your first method, but with compilation and then rename it to exe in the post-build like this:

```
move $(TARGET_OUTPUT_DIR)$(TARGET_OUTPUT_BASENAME).bat $(TARGET_OUTPUT_DIR)$(TARGET_OUTPUT_BASENAME).exe
echo [WHATEVER YOU NEED TO RUN] > $(TARGET_OUTPUT_DIR)$(TARGET_OUTPUT_BASENAME).bat
```

Comment: Seems like a bit of a hack, but I don't use Windows or Code::Blocks anymore :D. I still voted this answer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### Possible but less ideal solution:

After some time, I was able to come up with a solution. However, I am sure that there are better alternatives.

To use this method:

1. Create a new build target called `RunScript`.
2. Set the compiler to *No Compiler*.
3. In the project properties, set the type to ***Console application***.
4. **Uncheck** *Auto-generate filename extension*, and set the output filename to `RunButton.bat`.
5. Create a new file called `RunButton.bat` (or whatever you entered as the output filename).
6. Whatever you put in `RunButton.bat` will now be executed when you click the run button.
7. I also created a new [virtual target](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Creating_a_new_project#Virtual_Targets) that contained my `RunScript` target, and my main target, so that I don't have to switch targets whenever I want to test my application.

#### Problems with this method:

While this method does work, it is not ideal, as it requires you to have two extra targets (including the virtual target that I made for convenience). I would rather be able to just have everything contained in one target.

### Slightly better solution:

A new solution that I decided to use, is to simply use the [configure tools](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Configure_tools) menu to create a tool that points to a batch file that runs my compiled programs.

To use this method:

1. Go to *Tools>Configure Tools...>Add*.
2. Fill in the *name*, and point the executable to the script that you want to run when this tool is used.
3. Fill in any needed *parameters*. You can use the built in `${TARGET_OUTPUT_FILE}` macro to pass your output application as a parameter.
4. You can now use your tool by going to *Tools>{My tool}*, but you can set a hotkey by going to *Settings>Editor...>Keyboard shortcuts*.
5. Click the plus button by *Tools*, and click on your tool to set a shortcut for you tool.

#### Problems with this method:

While this method does eliminate the extra build targets, it doesn't let you run your script or run non-executable files by clicking the run button; which was the original intent. On top of this, you have to create a new tool anytime you want to add a new script.

---

I am hoping that someone else will be able to show me a better way of doing this, but for now this will work.